# Display date from Firestore React native

Tags: react-native, date, redux, expo, redux-firestore

I try to display the picked event date för my posts from Firestore using moment. Right now it just print The current day, so I display the date but not ont he right way. I get no error message. I have tried to change the timestamp to "dateUpload". but it gives me a print in my Text component  "invalid date". Do any have clue of what I can do?

This is how display it my flatlist:

```
postDate={moment(item.timestamp).format("ll")}
```

In my redux Action.js

```
export function fetchFollowingUsersPosts(uid) {
    return ((dispatch, getState) => {
        firebase.firestore()
            .collection("posts")
            .doc(uid)
            .collection("userPosts")
            .orderBy("creation", "asc")
            .get()
            .then((snapshot) => {

                const uid = snapshot.query.EP.path.segments[1];
                const user = getState().usersState.users.find(el => el.uid === uid);

                const posts = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
                    const { data: firebaseTimestamp, ...rest } = doc.data()
                    const id = doc.id;
                    const data = firebaseTimestamp ? moment(firebaseTimestamp.toDate()) : null
                  
                    return {
                      ...rest,
                      id,
                      user,
                      ...data
                    }
                  })

                //console.log(posts);
                dispatch({ type: USERS_POSTS_STATE_CHANGE, posts, uid,  })
            })
    })
}
```

Image on my database:

[image: Image on database]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `const data = firebaseTimestamp ? moment(firebaseTimestamp.toDate()) : null`, try this `const data = firebaseTimestamp ? firebaseTimestamp.toDate() : null` , so you'll be having a javascript Date object, instead of a Moment object.
Then, you can use it as you did `postDate={moment(item.timestamp).format("ll")}`, assuming that `item.timestamp` is the `Date` object from above

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It gives me the same result, I added a image on my database of what I try display (dateUpload).

Comment: Ok, I understand. But how does you field looks like when it comes from the firebase, if you print it?

Comment: When I print "item.timestamp" in my flatlist, it gives me the date for the current day. So I get the date, But if I try "item.dateUpload" it print "invalid date".

Comment: And in your `item` the field that you want to display `dateUpload`, which comes from the db, it is a date or a string? I'm not sure I got what's the connection between `item.timestamp` and `item.dateUpload`. That `invalid date` usually appears if you're trying to format an object (by using moment) which is not a valid Date one, neither a valid string

Comment: dateUpload is a date, you can see on my image I added in my question, or I'am wrong? Mm, I'am sure either, It's so strange. If I just print "item" and get same result like if I print  "item.timestamp".

Comment: I solved it. The problem was when I uploaded my post. I just added "moment" in the upload process. So that the date became to an string. Thank you so much for help!